# Create multiple parametherized JQueryUI dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-ui

In my application, I am using a lot of jQueryUI dialog boxes.
In order to reduce the length of code, and because I am using often the very same parameterization, I was wondering about a way to efficiently and easily create multiple dialogs.

I ended up with that: I've created multiple functions (`dialog_OkCancel`, `dialog_Input_OkCancel`, `dialog_YesNoCancel`) that call the same "main" `dialog_handler`.
That way I avoid calling the big main function and use only the little and easier ones.

These functions are pretty simple so I don't know what else to add. :)

Here is a working snippet of my code to illustrate that:

```js
// jQuery UI dialog custom management
function dialog_Handler({
  title,
  message,
  buttons,
  input
}) {
  $("<p>" + message + "</p>").dialog({ // Could use “var dialog = ”
    //autoOpen: false,     // false would prevents regular opening
    show: "drop",
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Overlay parameterization
      $("div.ui-widget-overlay").css({
        "background": "#000",
        "opacity": "0.4"
      });
      $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn();
      // Adds some more configuration if input needed
      if (input) {
        // Adds input field right under the message
        $(this).append('<br /><br /><input id="dialog_Input" style="width: 350px; padding: 4px;" type="text" value="' + input + '"><br />');
        // Binds “Enter” to press first button (usually “Ok”)
        $(this).keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    title: title,
    buttons: buttons,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: "fast"
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
    // Overlay fadeout
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      // Wait for the overlay to be faded out to try closing again
      if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
          $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
        });
        return false;
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
  });
  return;
}

function dialog_OkCancel({
  title,
  message,
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": function() {
      funk_Ok();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
  dialog_Handler({
    title,
    message,
    buttons
  });
  return;
}

function dialog_Input_OkCancel({
  title,
  message,
  input,
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": function() {
      funk_Ok();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
  dialog_Handler({
    title,
    message,
    buttons,
    input
  });
  return;
}

function dialog_YesNoCancel({
  title,
  message,
  funk_Yes,
  funk_No
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Yes": function() {
      funk_Yes();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "No": function() {
      funk_No();
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
  dialog_Handler({
    title,
    message,
    buttons
  });
  return;
}
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<html>

<body>

  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Sorry. :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Ok/Cancel</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_Input_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      input: "Type something…", 
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Give me more words ! :)"); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Input</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_YesNoCancel({
      title: "Just talking…",
      message: "Are you fine?",
      funk_Yes: function(){ console.log("You said “Yes”! :)"); },
      funk_No: function(){ console.log("You said “No”! :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Yes/No/Cancel</button>
</body>

</html>
```

This snippet is one piece of code out of many.
I would like that piece of code to be improved… So I could improve all others.
How would you do it?
What would be your method to improve the management of multiple functions?

Comment: The question you are asking is off-topic for Code Review. If you are interested in splitting methods into smaller ones or other refactoring techniques you probably should ask it on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) because we here are only improving working code. We don't discuss philosophical questions.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Your comment is funny to me, because I had posted that question  on stackoverflow and I was told in the comments to post it here, on codereview.stackexchange … :) And, in fact, I'd like my code to be improved if it's possible to do so. But the ways to improve it could vary from one coder to another. Don't you think?

Comment: In general it's ok to post it here however you are asking about a very specific problem: _I would like to know how you guys, create multiple smaller functions from a bigger one? What is the preferred method to do it?_ - this makes your quesiton off-topic for Code Review. If you were interested in _just_ improving your code and how it can be written in a more efficient etc way, then it'd be fine. You have to decide which one is it and pick the right stackexchange site for it.

Comment: @TakitIsy Many people recommend to put code here for review, while it doesn't meet our policies. It's gotten wrong there all of the time. Also asking for _"the best way"_ is always opinion based and won't generate good answers anywhere at the SE network.

Comment: @t3chb0t noted, I edited my question to… maybe, I hope, someday, get answers.

Comment: I have rolled back to the version with the added function, since it gives more context. Is my answer helpful?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your answer is helpful, and thanks for the nice feedback and suggestions.

Comment: Marveaux! I just added another optimization to simplify the functions that call `dialog_Handler()`

Comment: @SamOnela, I know I'm a little late but anyway… Thank you for your multiple edits and the explanations. I admit some of your code is "too complicated" for me ; for example the part where you say "Edit: The code can be simplified by using Object.assign()", ahah! :) Anyway, you helped me optimizing my code!

Comment: No worries - did you read about [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)? If not, I hope you will research it... Also, wow I messed up "_Marveilleux_" in my previous comment... shows how poor my French is... :/

Comment: @SamOnela, nice try for "Merveilleux !", I didn't understand what you were talking about ! :D I'll do read about, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question responses

> What would be your method to improve the management of multiple functions?

Looking at the three functions that call `dialog_Handler()` it appears that the main redundancies are with the click handlers for the buttons. See the response to the question below for one technique to simplify that logic.

In a comment, you asked:

> Do you know if there is any way to call `$(this).dialog("close");` without writing it inside each `function(){ }` of the `var buttons`?

Yes, you can abstract the function of closing the dialog out to a separate function, like:

```
function closeDialog() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

And that function can be bound to the functions for the button handlers using the Javascript function [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) for the `funk_Ok` parameter:

```
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Ok),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
```

And that close function could accept an optional callback function (for functions like `func_Ok`)- if that is a function, it can be called:

```
function closeDialog(callback) {
    (typeof callback === "function") && callback();
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

But the problem here is that `this` in this context is not the same as before - it is the `window` object. So one solution is to give the HTML element wrapped in the dialog object an [*id* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), like below:

```
const dialogId = 'message_dialog';
function dialog_Handler({
  title,
  message,
  buttons,
  input
}) {
  $("<p id='"+dialogId+"'>" + message + "</p>").dialog({ // Could use “var dialog = ”
```

And then in the `closeDialog` function, just reference that [*id* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) when closing the dialog:

```
function closeDialog(callback) {
    (typeof callback === "function") && callback();
    $('#'+dialogId).dialog("close");
}
```

See this in action in the snippet below:

#### Edit:

The code can be simplified by using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)- each function call to `dialog_Handler()` can use that to assign the `button` on the object that gets destructured:

```
dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
```

Then each function can omit the object properties it doesn't use (e.g. `message`, `title`)...

```js
//could use const
var dialogId = 'dialogContainer';
// jQuery UI dialog custom management
function dialog_Handler({
  title,
  message,
  buttons,
  input
}) {
  $("<p id='"+dialogId+"'>" + message + "</p>").dialog({ // Could use “var dialog = ”
    //autoOpen: false,                    // false would prevents regular opening
    show: "drop",
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Overlay parameterization
      $("div.ui-widget-overlay").css({
        "background": "#000",
        "opacity": "0.4"
      });
      $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn();
      // Adds some more configuration if input needed
      if (input) {
        // Adds input field right under the message
        $(this).append('<br /><br /><input id="dialog_Input" style="width: 350px; padding: 4px;" type="text" value="' + input + '"><br />');
        // Binds “Enter” to press first button (usually “Ok”)
        $(this).keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    title: title,
    buttons: buttons,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: "fast"
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
    // Overlay fadeout
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      // Wait for the overlay to be faded out to try closing again
      if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
          $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
        });
        return false;
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).dialog("destroy");
    }
  });
  return;
}
function closeDialog(callback) {
    (typeof callback === "function") && callback();
    $('#'+dialogId).dialog("close");
}
function dialog_OkCancel({
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Ok),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}

function dialog_Input_OkCancel({
  input,
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Ok),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}

function dialog_YesNoCancel({
  funk_Yes,
  funk_No
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Yes": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Yes),
    "No": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_No),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Sorry. :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Ok/Cancel</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_Input_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      input: "Type something…", 
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Give me more words ! :)"); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Input</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_YesNoCancel({
      title: "Just talking…",
      message: "Are you fine?",
      funk_Yes: function(){ console.log("You said “Yes”! :)"); },
      funk_No: function(){ console.log("You said “No”! :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Yes/No/Cancel</button>
```

One could also create a hidden element in the DOM, have `dialog_Handler()` update the text/HTML of that element and show it (using [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show) - or toggle a class name that shows it), then hide it (using [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)) when destroying the dialog. That way, the abstracted close function can just utilize that element.

```js
//could use const
var dialogContainer = $('#dialogContainer');
// jQuery UI dialog custom management
function dialog_Handler({
  title,
  message,
  buttons,
  input
}) {
  dialogContainer.text(message).show().dialog({ // Could use “var dialog = ”
    //autoOpen: false,                    // false would prevents regular opening
    show: "drop",
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Overlay parameterization
      $("div.ui-widget-overlay").css({
        "background": "#000",
        "opacity": "0.4"
      });
      $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn();
      // Adds some more configuration if input needed
      if (input) {
        // Adds input field right under the message
        $(this).append('<br /><br /><input id="dialog_Input" style="width: 350px; padding: 4px;" type="text" value="' + input + '"><br />');
        // Binds “Enter” to press first button (usually “Ok”)
        $(this).keydown(function(event) {
          if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $(this).parent().find("button:eq(1)").trigger("click");
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    title: title,
    buttons: buttons,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: "fast"
    },
    closeOnEscape: true,
    // Overlay fadeout
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      // Wait for the overlay to be faded out to try closing again
      if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
          $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
        });
        return false;
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).dialog("destroy");
      dialogContainer.hide();
    }
  });
  return;
}
function closeDialog(callback) {
    (typeof callback === "function") && callback();
    dialogContainer.dialog("close");
}
function dialog_OkCancel({
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Ok),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}

function dialog_Input_OkCancel({
  input,
  funk_Ok
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Ok": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Ok),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}

function dialog_YesNoCancel({
  funk_Yes,
  funk_No
}) {
  var buttons = {
    "Yes": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_Yes),
    "No": closeDialog.bind(null, funk_No),
    "Cancel": closeDialog
  }
  dialog_Handler(Object.assign(arguments[0], {buttons: buttons}));
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<p id="dialogContainer" style="display: none"></p>

<button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Sorry. :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Ok/Cancel</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_Input_OkCancel({
      title: "Title",
      message: "I do not have any idea for the message.",
      input: "Type something…", 
      funk_Ok: function(){ console.log("Give me more words ! :)"); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Input</button>
  <button class="dialog" onclick='dialog_YesNoCancel({
      title: "Just talking…",
      message: "Are you fine?",
      funk_Yes: function(){ console.log("You said “Yes”! :)"); },
      funk_No: function(){ console.log("You said “No”! :("); }
    });'>Dialog<br>Yes/No/Cancel</button>
```

---

## Other Review points

### Feedback

I like the usage of [the jQuery ui keycode constant](http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.ui.keycode/) for the enter key (i.e. `if (event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {`). I must admit I hadn't used that before but aim to do so in the future.

I really like the application of object destructuring for passing the named parameters - that is quite nifty!

### Suggestions

#### Cache DOM references

I see a couple places where DOM elements are looked up in succession, for example:

> ```
> if ($('.ui-widget-overlay').is(":visible")) {
>     $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut("fast", function() {
>       $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
>       $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
>     });
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

It is wise to cache those lookups in a variable - or actually, use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) to declare a constant unless there is a need to re-assign that value...

```
const widgetOverlay = $('.ui-widget-overlay');
// Wait for the overlay to be faded out to try closing again
if (widgetOverlay.is(":visible")) {
    widgetOverlay.fadeOut("fast", function() {
      widgetOverlay.hide();
      $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
    });
    return false;
}
```

#### Placeholder text

I would use the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute instead of the `value` attribute of the text input, since it appears that text is really prompting the user...

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type some text here..." />
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to call `$(this).dialog("close");`without writing it inside each `function(){ }` of the `var buttons` ?

Comment: See my updated answer